# Passing spaces in arguments for Visual Studio Pro 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug a command line program inside Visual Studio.  I am sharing my configuration with another machine using Box.  The paths I am passing have spaces in them and I haven't been successful in escaping the spaces so that instead of 3 arguments I get 9.  This is the relevant section from the original `launch.vs.json`.

```
{
  "type": "default",
  "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
  "projectTarget": "dispatcher.exe (src\\dispatcher\\dispatcher.exe)",
  "name": "dispatcher.exe (src\\dispatcher\\dispatcher.exe)",
  "args": [
    "C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\srasku-windows.json",
    "C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\static.json",
    "C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\dynamic.json"
  ]
}
```

None of these work.

```
"\"C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\srasku-windows.json\""
"\\"C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\srasku-windows.json\\""
"\\\"C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\srasku-windows.json\\\""
"\\\\"C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\srasku-windows.json\\\\""
```

How can I escape my spaces so that each argument is passed as a single argument instead of three.  Note: I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48709019/229058) but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to surround the spaces with singly-escaped double-quotes:

Here is the resultant section:

```
   {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "dispatcher.exe (src\\dispatcher\\dispatcher.exe)",
      "name": "dispatcher.exe (src\\dispatcher\\dispatcher.exe)",
      "currentDir": "C:\\Users\\212434537\\source\\Edge-Agent",
      "args": [
        "C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box\" \"Sync\\Edge\" \"Agent\\srasku-windows.json",
        "C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box\" \"Sync\\Edge\" \"Agent\\static.json",
        "C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box\" \"Sync\\Edge\" \"Agent\\dynamic.json"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround for this, is just to include the entire path in quotes, such as:

```
"C:\Users\212434537\Box Sync\Edge Agent\dynamic.json"
```

So, the escaped json becomes:

```
"\"C:\\Users\\212434537\\Box Sync\\Edge Agent\\dynamic.json\""
```